# How to set global hotkeys for Rhythmbox?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, rhythmbox

I would like to bind <kbd>F1</kbd> to play/pause and <kbd>F2</kbd> to next song globally
how to do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you go to System → Preferences → keyboard Shortcuts, you should see predefined shortcuts for Play, pause and so on. Click on the shortcut, on the right, to edit them.

However, using F1, F2 and so on may be problematic. Some legacy applications *may* open up their help whenever you press F1 for instance.

[image: screenshot, curtsey of ubuntuka.com]